# Pandas - Removing duplicates based on value in specific column

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
prod_id, prod_name, col_1, col_2, type
101, electronic, 10, 10, old
102, hardware, 2, 4, old
101, electronic, 10, 10, new
102, hardware, 2, 1, new
103, other, 22, 13, new
```

I am trying to update my Dataframe such that the updated Dataframe has the row with `type=old` if all other columns are same else using value from `type=new`

Final output:

```
prod_id, prod_name, col_1, col_2, type
101, electronic, 10, 10, old
102, hardware, 2, 1, new
103, other, 22, 13, new
```

Comment: did you look at the `Dataframe.drop_duplicates` method? It takes a `subset` parameter

Comment: @PaulH,  I did check out drop_duplicates method. What I am having trouble is apply drop_duplicates based on values in a column

Comment: did you read about the `subset` parameter?

Comment: also, check your example output. you have a "new" electronic row but you included the "old" row, which seems to contradict your problem statement

Comment: @PaulH, may be I did not put this correctly in the first place. If all rows (except `type`) are same, then I would prefer to take the first occurrence. If the values in any of the columns have a mismatch then I would like to take the latest row. On the other question, I did try  df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col_1','col_2']) would perform the duplicate elimination but I am trying to have a check on type column before applying the `drop_duplicates` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you  try with 2 boolean masks one checking if there is no duplicated values and type is new and another keeping the type='old' when there is duplicated,

```
u = df.drop("type",1)
c = ((u.duplicated(keep=False) & df['type'].eq('old')) | 
     (df['type'].eq('new') & ~u.duplicated(keep=False)) )
out = df[c].copy()
```

---

```
   prod_id   prod_name  col_1  col_2 type
0      101  electronic     10     10  old
3      102    hardware      2      1  new
4      103       other     22     13  new
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you want the result to contain a single row from each
source group of rows with each *prod_id* (more precisely, the last row).

The content of *type* column depends on whether all values in all *col_...*
columns, actually in columns from *2* to the last but one, are the same.

To get this result, define the following function:

```
def grpRes(grp):
    res = grp.iloc[-1,:]
    res.type = 'old' if np.unique(grp.values[:, 2:-1]).size == 1 else 'new'
    return res
```

Then apply this function to each group:

```
result = df.groupby('prod_id').apply(grpRes).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
   prod_id   prod_name  col_1  col_2 type
0      101  electronic     10     10  old
1      102    hardware      2      1  new
2      103       other     22     13  new
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution,
if and only if `type = 'old'` comes first in all the duplicated rows

```
columns = list(df.columns)
columns.remove('type')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=columns, keep='first')
```